# How would I test the Publish_permissions using facebook on an unsubmitted app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, prime31

Hello Everyone I am using the prime 31 facebook plugin for the Unity 3D engine  and I am running into an issue of testing out the ability for our users to post a message containing their score  onto their facebook wall.

I believe the issue is related to needing to add a publish_permission to my app yet I can't test this feature because I believe I have to have that permission approved to utilize it in my pap.

I also noticed that the approval process calls for explaining your usage of said permission and submitting your app with what I  imagine would be  a form of implementation .

**So I guess my confusion has to do with the general process of having my publish permissions approved and whether or not i can make use of the publish permissions in my not-approved app for testing at the very least .**

Answer (score 0):

You should always be able to test your permissions with the admin/test/developer users of the specific app.

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review which is stating that

> ...your app's developers will be able to see, and grant, any permission without requiring review by Facebook.
>
> Note: People who are listed in your app's Roles tab will have access to extended permissions without going through review (e.g. publish_actions or manage_pages). For example, if you use the Facebook Plugin for Wordpress to publish your blog posts to your Facebook Page or Profile, you do not need to submit for review so long as all your publishers are listed in your app's Roles tab.
>
> Also, if you're the developer of an app and are the only person using it, then your app doesn't need to go through review. Since you're the developer, all app capabilities should be available. You will still need to take your app out of developer mode, but you should be able to do that without going through review.